# pattern() function and onkeyup() function not working together

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

i am trying to let the screen show that the password inserted should be in a certain **regex** with **pattern**  when typing in the fields but when i used  **onkeyup()** to check if both passwords are matching the part with the onkeyup works but

the **pattern**  info box doesnt  show up anymore
so i was hoping to know why its not working ,if both functions are not allowed together or anything

**here is the html**

```
<div class ="signupbox">

<h1>Signup</h1>
<form action="">
   <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Enter Username"  pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$" title="please enter a username with only Letters and numbers[0-9]">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password"  pattern="(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[#@!%])[a-zA-Z0-9#@!%]{6,}" title="please enter a password with at least 1 capital letter and one special from[#@!%]" onkeyup='check();'/>
    <p>confirm password</p>
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="confirm Password"  onkeyup='check();' /> 
    <span id='message'></span>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="Signup" disabled  value="Signup" >
</form>
```

**here is the js**

```
var check = function() {
    if (document.getElementById('password').value ==
      document.getElementById('confirm_password').value) {
      document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'rgb(1, 126, 11)';
      document.getElementById('message').style.fontSize="20px"
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Passwords are matching";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.829)';
      document.getElementById('message').style.fontSize="20px"
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Passwords are not matching";
      sign.disabled=true;

}  
}
```

Comment: Check out if this helps. [Pattern Validation on Input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52081785/10462079)

Comment: so the message does not show up event though the code is executed correctly?
perhaps it would work better if you tried to do it the AngularJS-way?
Just create 2 spans with 2 different messages and appropriate styles and CSS display property set to `hidden`. The from JS you could just modify that one property and nothing else.

Comment: did you see any errors in the JS console in your browser?

Comment: @KamilJanowski  no there were  no errors in the browser but when i hover over it,it shows them in  a small yellow box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding `oninput="this.reportValidity()"` to all input fields with a pattern, in addition to your `onkeyup='check();'`, will show the browser-based validation feedback.